# Dynamic variable value on HTML with Django

Tags: python, html, django, dynamic, tags

I'm looking to display a constantly-changing python variable (that's read from a websocket server) onto a HTML file, currently i'm using a Django tag as it follows:

**templatetags/mytag.py**

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
current_value = 0

@register.filter
def c_value(placeholder):
    return current_value

#more code that modifies current_value reading from a websocket server
```

**index.html**

```
{% load mytag %}
<script>
function mytimer() {
  setInterval(function(){ 
                $('#stuff').html( {{ placeholder|c_value }} ); 
              }
              , 1000);
}
mytimer();
</script>

#some code from the website

<span id="stuff">Holder</span>
```

However naturally '{{ placeholder|c_value }}' only outputs the first ever value of 'current_value', which is 0 in this case, and so the source code of index.html ends up being:

**source code after '{{ placeholder|c_value }}'**

```
<script>
function mytimer() {
  setInterval(function(){ 
                $('#stuff').html( 0 ); 
              }
              , 1000);
}
mytimer();
</script>
```

Which is not desired since we would like to print the changing-value of 'current_value' each second.

What is the normal approach for these kind of dynamic texts? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you'll need to do to accomplish this behavior.

1. Set up a URL that returns the value you're interested in. For instance, set up your website so that the URL `http://example.com/c_value` returns a response with the correct information. It's usually a good idea to return the response in a JSON format; in Django, you can use the `JsonResponse` class to do this. Suppose you return the text:

   ```
   {
       "c_value": "foo"
   }
   ```
2. Change your page so that instead of loading in a variable from a template, it makes a request to the address that you set up. If you're using jQuery, you can use the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function to do this (or [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), which is just a shorthand function for $.ajax with only JSON data). You'll probably end up with something like this inside of your timer, assuming that the JSON returned matches the example I gave in step 1. (`data` will contain the JSON object that you sent from the server).

   ```
   $.ajax({
       dataType: "json",
       url: "http://example.com/c_value",
       success: function(data) {
           $('#stuff').html(data["c_value"]);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: This solved it, many thanks! Seems pretty basic now but i didn't know about AJAX at all, it all kind of makes sense now.

For the record:

1. I created a view for '/c_value' so that it 'my_site/c_value' answered a JSON with the relevant data from the server
2. Installed jQuery and then used AJAX to get the previously said relevant info from '/c_value'
3. Insterted this AJAX module into the function from the timer i specified before with setInterval

Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Keep in mind that you [don't have to use jQuery](https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/) to make an AJAX request -- it just reduces the amount of code to write.